# Haskell: ByteString issue when I use getArgs

Tags: haskell, cabal-sandbox

I am working inside a sandbox with ghc 7.10.3 and I have this simple code:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    [ newOauthConsumerKey, newOauthConsumerSecret ] -> do
      let appOauth = newOAuth { oauthServerName       = "api.twitter.com"
                              , oauthConsumerKey    = newOauthConsumerKey
                              , oauthConsumerSecret = newOauthConsumerSecret
                              }
  ...
```

when I compile it with these dependencies in my cabal file:

```
base
, authenticate-oauth
, http-conduit
, aeson
, text
```

I keep on get (after cleaning and rebuilding the sandbox) the following errors:

```
src/Test/Main.hs:60:55:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’
                   with ‘bytestring-0.10.6.0:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
    Expected type: bytestring-0.10.6.0:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString
      Actual type: String
    In the ‘oauthConsumerKey’ field of a record
    In the expression:
      newOAuth
        {oauthServerName = "api.twitter.com",
         oauthConsumerKey = newOauthConsumerKey,
         oauthConsumerSecret = newOauthConsumerSecret}

src/Test/Main.hs:61:55:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’
                   with ‘bytestring-0.10.6.0:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
    Expected type: bytestring-0.10.6.0:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString
      Actual type: String
    In the ‘oauthConsumerSecret’ field of a record
    In the expression:
      newOAuth
        {oauthServerName = "api.twitter.com",
         oauthConsumerKey = newOauthConsumerKey,
         oauthConsumerSecret = newOauthConsumerSecret}
```

I have already googled and checked different similar answers but I cannot make it work. Any idea?

**Solution**

The problem was due to the fact that in the code there was an import for `import Data.Text` that includes a `pack` which is different from the `pack` required for `Data.ByteString.Char8`. Once I have included it, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

The fields `oauthConsumerKey` and `oauthConsumerSecret` are supposed to contain `ByteString`s and not `String`s which is what `getArgs` returns. You need to use [pack](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:pack) to convert your `newOauthConsumer*` values.

Comment: I have already tried it and it didn't work (forgot to write it the question). If you use a hardcoded string inside the newOAuth it will work.